# SQL Check for null values in variables

Tags: sql-server, null

I am trying to compare a table value to a variable which can be `null`, however since we cannot equate this to null hence this is not comparable.

```
declare @test varchar(33) -- This can or cannot be NULL;
select * from [dbo].[ViewsConfiguration] where PolicyId= 139 and EventName= @test
```

This can be done using `switch` or `if` , however looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: you can use `ISNULL/ COALESCE` like this `and ISNULL(EventName,'')= ISNULL(@test,'')`

Comment: @ughai can u please add it in the answer so that I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL / COALESCE`. Your query would be like

```
declare @test varchar(33) -- This can or cannot be NULL;
select * from [dbo].[ViewsConfiguration] where PolicyId= 139 and ISNULL(EventName,'')= ISNULL(@test,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare both to `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(33) 
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[ViewsConfiguration]
WHERE   PolicyId = 139
        AND ( EventName = @testd
              OR ( EventName IS NULL
                   AND @testd IS NULL
                 )
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)?

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

Something like

```
select * 
from [dbo].[ViewsConfiguration] 
where PolicyId= 139 
and EventName= ISNULL(@test,EventName)
```

Comment: This is not sargable  and it will filter out eventnames where they are NULLs

Answer (score 0):

You could check for it explicitly with the `is` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [dbo].[ViewsConfiguration] 
WHERE  PolicyId = 139 AND 
       (EventName = @test OR (@test IS NULL AND EventName IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `null` rows if `@test` is null you can use a combination of [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177562.aspx) and [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ViewsConfiguration] WHERE PolicyId= 139 
     AND ISNULL(NULLIF(EventName, @test), NULLIF(@test, EventName)) IS NULL
```

`ISNULL(NULLIF(EventName, @test), NULLIF(@test, EventName))` delivers null if the values are both `null` or if they are equal:

```
EventName      @test        Result
----------------------------------
null           null         null   
[value]        null         [value]   
null           [value]      [value]  
[value1]       [value2]     [value1]  
[value]        [value]      null
```